# Environment with default output and command to change it

Tags: package-writing, package-options, environment-variables

In the past for my dissertation I made a code that was outputting the result as a tex file for each experiment, generating a new table every time, but most of the entries I expected were the same. It did its job, but I couldn't find at first glance what changed between experiment to experiment in the LaTeX code.

I could not find anything similar so I need to ask. Did anyone know a package to do something similar to this.

Let say I am running several experiments and I need to output a table for each one.

1. The name of the input is always the same, but their value might change. [around 40 inputs]
2. I expect 90% of the entries to be always the same
3. For readability, I want to be able to input ONLY the value I change [so not an array with 40 numbers just to change one]

Is there a package for an environment (think something like equation or feynman) that does something similar to this:

```
\begin{specialtext}
\end{specialtext}
```

-> produce default table

```
\begin{specialtext}
\variable_X{40}
\end{specialtext}
```

-> produce the default table in which the only value changed is the one of variable X

I'm not looking for someone "writing the code for me", I'm just curious to find if there is some existing package out there that
I can study or some paper that deal with a similar problem (and doesn't resort to "use an external python/matlab/C++ code to generate the full table")

UPDATE:

The answer using Lua solved my problem. An alternative that seemed to worked well was using the keycommand package that allow to introduce options in a key:value way and set a default

Comment: My bad it was a simple question:
I used the keycommand package.

Comment: Please add this to your question so that all information is together in the same place.  It's allowed for anyone to edit their own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider to use Lua (embedded in LuaTeX), there's a proof of concept.

The environment `MyEnv` creates a table with ten elements (customization is possible, tho). Functions defined via Lua make quite what their names suggest. So, every time you use `MyEnv` a table is cleaned (if it has been used before), it is filled with elements according to a pattern (I've chosen `i^2+1`) and a `\DisturbTable` macro is defined with two arguments, the position to be changed and the string to be passed. It will work only inside `MyEnv` as `\begin{MyEnv}` and `\end{MyEnv}` clean the content of the table.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
userdata = userdata or {}
userdata.MyTable = userdata.MyTable or {}
userdata.CleanTable = function()
    userdata.MyTable = {}
end
userdata.MakeTable = function(num)
    for i=1,num do
        table.insert(userdata.MyTable, "$a_{"..tostring(math.floor(i^2+1)).."}$")
    end
end
userdata.PrintTable = function()
    tex.print([[\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline ]])
    tex.print(table.concat(userdata.MyTable, [[ \\ \hline ]]))
    tex.print([[ \\ \hline \end{tabular}]])
end

userdata.DisturbTable = function(num,str)
    if (num > 0) and (num <= #userdata.MyTable) then
        userdata.MyTable[num] = str
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\CleanTable}{\directlua{userdata.CleanTable()}}
\newcommand{\MakeTable}{\directlua{userdata.MakeTable(10)}}
\newcommand{\DisturbTable}[2]{\directlua{userdata.DisturbTable(#1, \luastringN{#2})}}
\newcommand{\PrintTable}{\directlua{userdata.PrintTable()}}
\newenvironment{MyEnv}{\CleanTable\MakeTable}{\PrintTable\CleanTable}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}
    \DisturbTable{1}{I'm an invader}
\end{MyEnv}
\begin{MyEnv}
    \DisturbTable{2}{Nice} \DisturbTable{10}{Not nice} \DisturbTable{5}{Hello!}
\end{MyEnv}
\begin{MyEnv}
    \DisturbTable{12}{Won't appear}
\end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ooooh nice. This would work better and it's more flexible than just using key:values. Thanks +1